# How to print ESC/POS network with swift

Tags: swift, printing, escpos

I want to print from iOS app to thermal printer (connected to a network) that use ESC/POS command.
I have already a framework that translate a text to ESC/POS command but I don’t know how to send it to the printer.
I think that the steps are:

1. connection to printer
2. send code to printer
3. close connection to printer when job is done.

Somebody can help me?